# Rails: generate a screenshot but how to save it to / retrive it from S3 via carrierwave/fog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I can generate a screenshot via a gem 'Gastly'
Without a model, only a request to screens controller, a screenshot will be taken and saved to a public folder.

ScreensController:

```
def index

id = current_user.id
first_name = current_user.first_name
target = "http://localhost:3000/users/#{id}?start_date=#{params[:start_date]}"
@screenshot = Gastly.screenshot(target)
@screenshot.selector = '.simple-calendar'
@image = @screenshot.capture
date_mark = params[:start_date].split('-')[0..1].join('-')

if @image.save("public/images/image-#{id}-#{first_name}-#{date_mark}.png")
  redirect_to user_path(current_user)
end

end
```

I tried to store the file to S3 by using carrierwave and fog.

1. I generated ScreenshotUploader: `rails g uploader Screenshot`
2. in screenshot_uploader.rb, I uncommented `include CarrierWave::MiniMagick`; `storage :fog` ; and as for `def store_dir`, I just put "uploads/" instead of the default `"uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}` since there's no model.
3. Then i modified the ScreensController above:

   ```
   if @image.save("public/images/image-#{id}-#{first_name}-#{date_mark}.png")
   uploader = ScreenshotUploader.new
   uploader.store!(@image)
   redirect_to user_path(current_user)
   end
   ```

Result: The screenshot is just saved to the public folder and nothing in S3.

Comment: And your rails logs show no output from the failure of the CarrierWave uploader? If thats failing it must be displaying some errors?

Comment: I'm sorry if I did this wrong: I used `tail -f log/development.log` to check the log, but didn't see anything regarding CarrierWave.

Comment: Try it in a rails console; place a static image on your hard drive somewhere and just try it out: `uploader = ScreenshotUploader.new; uploader.store!("tmp/foo.png");`

Comment: i put apple.png in tmp folder of the project and the result is:


[1] pry(main)> uploader = ScreenshotUploader.new
=> #<ScreenshotUploader:0x00007f94c0eab5f8 @model=nil, @mounted_as=nil>
[2] pry(main)> uploader.store!("tmp/apple.png")
````CarrierWave::FormNotMultipart: You tried to assign a String or a Pathname to an uploader, for security reasons, this is not allowed.````

 ````If this is a file upload, please check that your upload form is multipart encoded.
from /Users/gloriading/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/carrierwave-1.2.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:122:in `cache!' ````

Comment: Ah ok, then feed it a valid File reference ```a = ScreenshotUploader.new; file = File.open("tmp/foo.png"); a.store!(file)```

Comment: Thanks! It works. In screenshot controller, after the screenshot has been saved to the public folder, I added:  `uploader = ScreenshotUploader.new`;
  `file = File.open("public/images/image-#{id}-#{first_name}-#{date_mark}.png")`;   `uploader.store!(file)`.
The the screenshot will be saved to S3. 
However, I'm not sure how I can retrieve and show the image. In the console I tried `a = ScreenshotUploader.new` ;
`a.retrieve_from_store!('image-1-Gloria-2018-02.png')`; 
Then I can get the image, and by calling a.path I get `uploads/screenshots/image-1-Gloria-2018-02.png`

Comment: So in another controller, I added the codes to get the path, `    a = ScreenshotUploader.new`; ` a.retrieve_from_store!('image-1-Gloria-2018-02.png')`;  `@screenshot_path = a.path` In the view, i tried: `<%= image_tag(@screenshot_path) %>` but this gives _The asset "uploads/screenshots/image-1-Gloria-2018-02.png" is not present in the asset pipeline._; Then I tried `<img src="<%= @screenshot_path %>" />`, in the chrome console, it gives _404 (Not Found)_

Comment: You can get the URL to the remote asset by calling `url`, so `a.url` where `a` is an instance of `ScreenshotUploader`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works, and it brings up another question: since the screenshot and file upload do not depend on models , I won't be able to list the screenshots a user takes and stored in S3. Is that correct?

Comment: You are correct; without persisting the knowledge of that screenshot (not the actual file itself to S3) to a database of some kind you wont be able to in turn reference those screenshots. Unless you actually crawled/listed S3 itself.

Comment: Thanks again. I added a model to store the path (`"image-#{id}-#{first_name}-#{date_mark}.png"`) of a screenshot upon uploading to S3, and also associate it with users. Now I have another question, i want to have a selection menu so user can select, and the image will be shown in that webpage. Will start a new post to ask further questions.